# Golang: append file to an existing tar archive

Tags: go

How would I append a file to an existing tar archive in Go?  I don't see anything obvious in the [docs](http://golang.org/pkg/archive/tar/) on how to do it.

I have a tar file that has already been created and I want to add more to it after it has already been closed.

**EDIT**

Altering the example in the docs and following the answer given, I'm still not getting the expected result.  The first three files are being written to the tar but when I close and open up the file again to write to it, the new file is never being written.  The code runs fine. I don't know what I'm missing.

The following code gives me a tar file with three files in it: readme.txt, gopher.txt, todo.txt.  foo.bar never gets written.

```
package main

import (
    "archive/tar"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Create("/home/jeff/Desktop/test.tar")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    tw := tar.NewWriter(f)

    var files = []struct {
        Name, Body string
    }{
        {"readme.txt", "This archive contains some text files."},
        {"gopher.txt", "Gopher names:\nGeorge\nGeoffrey\nGonzo"},
        {"todo.txt", "Get animal handling licence."},
    }
    for _, file := range files {
        hdr := &tar.Header{
            Name: file.Name,
            Size: int64(len(file.Body)),
        }
        if err := tw.WriteHeader(hdr); err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
        if _, err := tw.Write([]byte(file.Body)); err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
    }
    if err := tw.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    f.Close()

    // Open up the file and append more things to it

    f, err = os.OpenFile("/home/jeff/Desktop/test.tar", os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, os.ModePerm)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    tw = tar.NewWriter(f)

    test := "this is a test"

    hdr := &tar.Header{
        Name: "foo.bar",
        Size: int64(len(test)),
    }

    if err := tw.WriteHeader(hdr); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    if _, err := tw.Write([]byte(test)); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    if err := tw.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    f.Close()

}
```

Comment: commenting out the trailer section will result in an invalid tar file.  It's probably a bad idea.

Comment: that's what I was thinking but I can still access it like a normal tar file

Comment: @Jeff have a look at the answer I provided. Using `Seek` is still slightly dodgy, but it does result in a valid tar file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`tar` file specification](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tar&sektion=5) states:

> > A tar archive consists of a series of 512-byte records.  Each file system
> >          object requires a header record which stores basic metadata (pathname,
> >          owner, permissions, etc.) and zero or more records containing any file
> >          data.  The end of the archive is indicated by two records consisting
> >          entirely of zero bytes.

The Go implementation of adding these two zero filled records [happens here](https://golang.org/src/archive/tar/writer.go?s=11724:11867#L388) .

To get around the `tar` file format trailer (basically 1024 bytes of nothing) you could replace the lines:

```
f, err = os.OpenFile("/home/jeff/Desktop/test.tar", os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, os.ModePerm)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
tw = tar.NewWriter(f)
```

With:

```
f, err = os.OpenFile("/home/jeff/Desktop/test.tar", os.O_RDWR, os.ModePerm)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
if _, err = f.Seek(-1024, os.SEEK_END); err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
tw = tar.NewWriter(f)
```

It opens the file read / write (instead of append / write-only) and then seeks to 1024 bytes before the end of the file and writes from there.

It works, <s>but it *is* a horrible hack.</s>

EDIT: After understanding the `tar` file spec a little better, I no longer believe this is such a hack.

Full code: http://play.golang.org/p/0zRScmY4AC

Comment: IIRC tar archives are padded to the next block anyway, so this seeking is not neccessary.

Comment: @FUZxxl, you're very likely correct. With the test code given it didn't work without dropping the last 1024 bytes before writing to the file. As I said, it's a hack that just reverses the final action of the tar.Close() function. See http://golang.org/src/pkg/archive/tar/writer.go?s=8343:8486#L305 .

Comment: If you have a look at the source file [writer.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/archive/tar/writer.go), observe tw.pad. Each file is padded to the next full block.

Comment: @FUZxxl, I've updated my answer with a link to the tar file spec explaining why this works.

Comment: I don't think it's a horrible hack at *all*, it's well within the bounds of the specification and would only fail on files wherein the last 1024 bytes are not trailer blocks. Of course, this would only happen if, for example, you created your own tar package (copied the source) and commented out the trailer section on the tw.Close() call.

Comment: I have found this is not a general solution, unfortunately. Using the `tar` command you can confirm this, that the padding at the end of an archive file is basically arbitrary: https://twitter.com/cperciva/status/1476774314623913987 -- so while this answer is correct if you control the writer, it is less helpful in general. One will have to scan the entire archive and count bytes to determine where the content ends (esp. considering an archive could end with a file with a bunch of 0 bytes as content).

Answer (score 4):

It's just a writer interface so write bytes to it after writing your files header.

```
import (
  "archive/tar"
  "os"
)

f, err := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, os.ModePerm)
if err != nil {
// handle error here
}

hdr := tar.Header{}
// populate your header
tw := tar.NewWriter(f)
// append a file
tw.WriteHeader(hdr)
tw.Write(content_of_file_as_bytes)
```

http://golang.org/pkg/archive/tar/#Writer tells you all you need to know.

EDIT: It turns out that tar files get a trailer written to the end when it's closed. So even though you are writing new data to the tar archive it won't be read past that trailer. So instead it looks like you'll have to read in the tar archive first and then rewrite the whole archive to disk which is suboptimal. The package doesn't support the necessary stuff to append to them though so that's the best I can recommend right now.

Comment: it's a good idea that we can look into its implementation : https://code.google.com/p/go/codesearch#go/src/pkg/archive/tar/writer.go&q=tar&sq=package:go&l=5&dr=C

Comment: Thanks for your time.  That's what I was expecting but I can't get it to work.  I've edited my question to show the code sample I'm using.

Comment: It looks like the trailer may be a 1KB empty byte slice so shouldn't be too hard to deal with. See http://golang.org/src/pkg/archive/tar/writer.go?s=8343:8486#L305 ("zeroBlock" is a var currently defined as a 512B byte slice)

Comment: @Jeff and Jeremy, See my hackish answer for a way around the tar file trailer issue. Hope it helps, it seems to work.

Comment: yeah I did the same thing when I was investigating but decided that was probably a terrible thing to recommend on stack overflow. Glad someone else did :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found the accepted solution by @Intermernet to be basically correct, except that the padding at the end of an archive is generally arbitrary (unless you control the writer too).

This works for me as far as I can tell so far:

```golang
var lastFileSize, lastStreamPos int64
tr := tar.NewReader(output)
for {
    hdr, err := tr.Next()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    lastStreamPos, err = output.Seek(0, io.SeekCurrent)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    lastFileSize = hdr.Size
}

const blockSize = 512
newOffset := lastStreamPos + lastFileSize
// shift to next-nearest block boundary (unless we are already on it)
if (newOffset % blockSize) != 0 {
    newOffset += blockSize - (newOffset % blockSize) 
}
_, err := output.Seek(newOffset, io.SeekStart)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

tw := tar.NewWriter(output)
defer tw.Close()

// ... proceed to write to tw as usual ...
```

I'm not 100% sure why this works. But the basic idea is to scan the archive, find the offset of the start of the last file, then skip over it, then align to the nearest block boundary, then start overwriting from there.