# How add a file to an existing zip file using Golang

Tags: go, zip

We can create a zip new file and add files using Go Language.

But, how to add a new file with existing zip file using GoLang?

If we can use Create function, how to get the zip.writer reference?

Bit confused.

Comment: It looks like this isn't supported. You might want to file a feature-request for this feature to be supported.

Comment: Any recommendations for working with zip files in GoLang other than the native archive/zip package on my requirement?

Comment: Invoke the `zip` command line utility.

Comment: Invoking zip command line util is not preferred. Because, I am trying to do all the stuff within the application and want to avoid any dependency of 3rd party tools.

Also, my app is running on multiple OSes and I am reluctant to keep the different tools for this requirement. Is there better alternative to built in archive/zip package?

Comment: Not that I know of. You might want to write your own bindings to an existing zip library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After more analysis, i found that, it is not possible to add any files with the existing zip file.

But, I was able to add files with tar file by following the hack given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323995/golang-append-file-to-an-existing-tar-archive) URL.

Comment: See here also. They decided this feature is hard to match with existing Go APIs and hence discarded it. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15626

Answer (score 2):

you can:

1. copy old zip items into a new zip file;
2. add new files into the new zip file;

```golang
zipReader, err := zip.OpenReader(zipPath)
targetFile, err := os.Create(targetFilePath)
targetZipWriter := zip.NewWriter(targetFile)

for _, zipItem := range zipReader.File {
    zipItemReader, err := zipItem.Open()
    header, err := zip.FileInfoHeader(zipItem.FileInfo())
    header.Name = zipItem.Name
    targetItem, err := targetZipWriter.CreateHeader(header)
    _, err = io.Copy(targetItem, zipItemReader)
}

addNewFiles(targetZipWriter) // IMPLEMENT YOUR LOGIC
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I have not attempted this yet with a zip file that already exists and then writing to it, I believe you should be able to add files to it.

This is code I have written to create a conglomerate zip file containing multiple files in order to expedite uploading the data to another location.  I hope it helps!

```
type fileData struct {
    Filename string
    Body     []byte
}

func main() {
    outputFilename := "path/to/file.zip"

    // whatever you want as filenames and bodies
    fileDatas := createFileDatas()

    // create zip file
    conglomerateZip, err := os.Create(outputFilename)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer conglomerateZip.Close()

    zipWriter := zip.NewWriter(conglomerateZip)
    defer zipWriter.Close()

    // populate zip file with multiple files
    err = populateZipfile(zipWriter, fileDatas)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

}

func populateZipfile(w *zip.Writer, fileDatas []*fileData) error {
    for _, fd := range fileDatas {
        f, err := w.Create(fd.Filename)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        _, err = f.Write([]byte(fd.Body))
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        err = w.Flush()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old and already has an answer, but if performance isn't a key concern for you (making the zip file isn't on a hot path for example) you *can* do this with the archive/zip library by creating a new writer and copying the existing files into it then adding your new content. Something like this:

```
zw := // new zip writer from buffer or temp file
newFileName := // file name to add
reader, _ := zip.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(existingFile), int64(len(existingFile)))
for _, file := range reader.File {
    if file.Name == newFileName {
        continue // don't copy the old file over to avoid duplicates
    }
    fw, _ := zw.Create(file.Name)
    fr, _ := file.Open()
    io.Copy(fw, fr)
    fr.Close()
}
```

Then you would return the new writer and append files as needed. If you aren't sure which files might overlap you can turn that if check into a function with a list of file names you will eventually add. You can also use this logic to remove a file from an existing archive.

Answer (score 0):

Now in 2021, there is still no support for appending files to an existing archive.
But at least it is now possible to add already-compressed files, i.e. we don't anymore have to decompress & re-compress files when duplicating them from old archive to new one.

(**NOTE:** this only applies to Go 1.17+)

So, based on examples by @wongoo and @Michael, here is how I would implement appending files now with the minimum performance overhead (you'll want to add error handling though):

```
zr, err := zip.OpenReader(zipPath)
defer zr.Close()
zwf, err := os.Create(targetFilePath)
defer zwf.Close()
zw := zip.NewWriter(zwf)
defer zwf.Close() // or not... since it will try to wrote central directory

for _, zipItem := range zrw.File {
    if isOneOfNamesWeWillAdd(zipItem.Name) {
        continue // avoid duplicate files!
    }
    zipItemReader, err := zipItem.OpenRaw()
    header := zipItem.FileHeader // clone header data
    targetItem, err := targetZipWriter.CreateRaw(&header) // use cloned data
    _, err = io.Copy(targetItem, zipItemReader)
}

addNewFiles(zw) // IMPLEMENT YOUR LOGIC
```