# Convert io.ReadCloser into io.Reader in Go

Tags: go, zip, reader, writer

I am using the `archive/zip` library and I need to make a modification to a file inside a zip archive on the fly before I upload it to s3. Currently I am getting back an `io.ReadCloser` but the function I am using to modify the user requires an `io.Reader`:

```
//Function Signature:
Convert(r io.Reader, w io.Writer, ...)
```

I also need an `io.Writer`... Bonus points if you can help me determine how to create a writer as well. Here is some example code that may give some context:

```
for _, f := range r.File {
    if filepath.Ext(f.Name) != ".txt" {

      _, filename := path.Split(f.Name)
      var rc io.ReadCloser
      if rc, err = f.Open(); err == nil {

        // FIXME: Convert
        if err = Convert(rc.Reader, *zip.Writer.Create(f.Name), ...); err != nil {
          errStr := fmt.Sprintf("Unable to convert")
          log.Println(errStr)

        } else {

          log.Println("Success!")

        }

        // Upload to s3
        .....
      }   
    }   
  }
```

Comment: A type that implements the `io.ReadCloser` interface, also implements the `io.Reader` interface, so a value of such a type does not need to be converted to `io.Reader`.

Comment: Lol. My God. Sometimes the most obvious solutions are the hardest to see :facepalm:

Comment: Any idea how to create a writer though?

Comment: There are lots of writers. Do you want to write to a file? A buffer? A network connection? Stdout? Try googling "go write to " and whatever it is you want to write to.

Comment: It depends on where you want to write the data to. An `*os.File` for example implements all of the interfaces mentioned here,  including `io.Writer`, so, you could, open another file into which to write the (un)zipped data.

Comment: I want to write to the zipped file.... So Idk if that's possible on the fly or if I will need to write it somewhere and then shove that into the archive after I'm done. That's what I'm kinda understanding from what you're saying @mkopriva

Comment: @NoahGary you can't modify the contents *during* archiving without modifying the original source code of the archiver. What you can do however is to modify the data *before* or *after* archiving (which one is up to you) and then persist it by writing to a file, or to s3 directly. So I believe what you need is, in effect, a "chain" of writers, i.e. zipw->mymodw->filew or mymodw->zipw->filew.

Comment: @mkopriva The files are already archived... I just need to 1. read one of those files... 2. modify it... 3. overwrite the original inside the archive. The upload to s3 will be a zip archive with my modifications.

Comment: Forgive me if I didn't understand what you said completely about the chain of writers.

Comment: The `convert` function should do all of the modifications for me and save it. I just need to provide it with a proper writer. I'm hoping this is possible without a bunch of extra work but I understand this may not be so simple.

Comment: @NoahGary If you're asking whether it's possible to modify (by changing or adding a *few* bytes), or convert (by complete translation of *all* bytes from A to B) **individual** files in a zip archive without having to first unarchive the files, and then, after the changes, archive them all back, then I do not know the answer but you should consider re-framing your question as such, because as it stands now it is unclear what you are asking. And the part of the question that's in the title has already been resolved.

Comment: I think I'll probably end up doing something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28513486/how-add-a-file-to-an-existing-zip-file-using-golang

Comment: I will probably delete this question as it is a duplicate of the one I just mentioned. I understand what I need to do now. Just kind of wish I could modify the archive rather than decompressing and re-compressing. But that's fine too. I understand why this isn't possible now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How add a file to an existing zip file using Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28513486/how-add-a-file-to-an-existing-zip-file-using-golang)

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 It does. Thank you. I linked it above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. To convert an `io.ReadCloser` to an `io.Reader` you do:

   ### NOTHING!

   An `io.ReadCloser` is already an `io.Reader` by virtue of the fact that all methods of the `io.Reader` interface (specifically a `Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)` method) are also provided by `io.ReadCloser`.
2. Converting an `io.Reader` into an `io.Writer` is an entirely different matter. You can't really do that in any general way. You'll need to elaborate on what you're trying to do.